# Why iPhone could not access website developed in jSF?

Tags: iphone, jsf-2, glassfish, glassfish-3

i developed a new website to the company where i work :

http://50.19.242.172:8080/BrainSet/

it's running in a EC2 machine from Amazon Web Service.

Everything is fine, but when i try to access from a iPhone (version 3GS) my website crashes.

I don't understand why this happen, glassfish should not to interpret the jsf tags and show a html page ?
This happen with someone before ?

Any suggestion or idea why this is happening ?

**UPDATE:**
I install an Android emulator,this is what it should show :
[image: Opening in PC web browser]
And this is what it show in smartphone (Android emulator) :
[image: Opening in smartphone]

Thanks,
Valter Henrique.

Comment: Why are you hijacking the favicon from Stackoverflow? Why is the site extremely wide? (perhaps iPhone can't just handle that width?) Can you describe "my website crashes" in a bit more detail?

Comment: The web site crashes or the browser in the iPhone crashes?

Comment: @BalusC, I'm gonna change the favicon, i forgot. The website is not wide, is just the pictures that it's. But iPhone should not handle with any size of page or image ? I saw today what happens and when i access it shows the code of the page, that's what happens.

Comment: @AlanObject, the web site crashes.

Comment: So, according the screenshot, "my website crashes" thus *actually* means that you got a text/plain response? What does the response headers say? Please try to elaborate the problem in developer's perspective not in enduser's perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake, I developed the `index.xhtml` page without `<h:head>` and `<h:body>` tags, because it has given some errors with `.css` files, but now I have renamed it to `index.html`, and everthing works fine, thanks by the help everyone.